# How can i disable my stringElement in Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How can i disable my `StringElement` in `Monotouch.Dialog`?

```cs
StringElement seBlockAD = new StringElement ("blockad", new NSAction (()=>{
    some code....
}));
```

Comment: i dont't want anyone touch it in disable mode.